# Axios data from .NET showing undefined in Vue

Tags: .net, vue.js, infinite-scroll

I have been passed an endpoint to use to create infinite scrolling on the frontend using either Vue or Vanilla JS.

I have the following script:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script type="module" async>
    import Vue from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.esm.browser.js'//Vue
    
    Vue.prototype.$http = axios;
    var vm = new Vue({
        el: '#nft-list-hp',
        data: {
            pageData: ''
        },
        mounted() {
            
            this.$http.get('/_more?page=1').then(response => this.pageData = response.data.data);
           
        }
    })

</script>
```

However pageData in Vue is showing undefined, when I check the response of the endpoint, I see the HTML that I want to display using Infinite scroll.

Why would pageData be showing undefined?

Answer (score 0):

Data should be a function:

```
data: {
    pageData: ''
},
```

should be

```
    data() {
        return {
          pageData: ''
       }
    },
```

Comment: data actually works correctly as it is in this instance, I tried changing to a function but I get the same result still

Comment: It seems that who created Vue doesn't know your findings then..
> The data option for a component is a function
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/data-methods.html#data-properties

Comment: For your problem, you did not publish where you do use the `pageData `, but because you're assigning it with an http request, that is async, will most likely be undefined because on component mount is actually undefined and will get defined just when it completes (if it does).

Comment: I have not used it yet, I am trying to build infinite scroll on the page, but in order to do that I need pageDate to show the HTML being sent in the response. I see the HTML under the network tab, but it shows undefined after being assigned to pageData. What would be the correct way to assign using an http request?

Comment: Where do you see "shows undefined after being assigned to pageData" ?

Comment: When I try doing a console.log of pageData after axios gets the data

Comment: If you put the full code, will be easy to fix